# NGINX: strip querystring in rewrite

Tags: nginx, 301-redirect

I'd like to make a 301 rewrite to the sites's index without any querystring. Like this:

`http://example.com/anypage.asp?anyvar=anyvalue`

To:

`http://example.com/`

Here's a real example:

`http://atipico.com.br/conteudo.asp?P_categ=23`

I am trying to follow this: http://wiki.nginx.org/NginxHttpRewriteModule#rewrite

(The commented are my attempts):

```
location ~ /conteudo\.asp(.*)$ {
    #rewrite ^ / permanent;
    #rewrite ^ /? permanent;
    #return 301 /;
    #return 301 /?;
    #if ($args) { return 301 /; }
}
```

It always rewrites to `http://atipico.com.br/?P_categ=23`

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you try `rewrite ^/conteudo.asp$ /? permanent;` (i.e. without the location block) - seems to work fine for me (even without the start/end delimiters, and without the question mark)

Comment: It looks fine, but why do you extract the GET parameters into a variable which you then don't use? Not sure how it behaves in this situation then.

Comment: `rewrite ^ /? permanent;` works fine. Did you clear browser cache or try with another web browser?

Comment: Yes I had to clear browser cache for updates to have effect, didn't think this would be the case but tried it after reading @quanta comment and fixed my issue

Answer (score 6):

This is the best rule I found and it is working to me:

```
rewrite ^/content /? permanent;
```

Meaning, rewrite all requests:

- starting in the root of the domain (^/)
- than followed by "content"
- to the root (index) of the site (/)
- removing all query strings it might have (?)
- and show a 301 redirect in the headers.

I guess that's it.

Comment: Adding as a reference for OP: http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpRewriteModule#rewrite It will explain more details about the ? notation which drops the arguments.